# React state has array as property, but when passed it gets nested into a self-titled object?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React state that looks like so:

```
  state = {
    itemList: []
  };
```

I have a render function that looks like this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ListingContainer itemList={this.state.itemList} />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

The `ListingContainer` component looks like this:

```
const ListingContainer = (itemList) => {
    return(
        <div>
            {
                // getting type error, itemList.map is not a function
                itemList.map(({data}) => <Item data={data} />)
            }
        </div>
    );
};
```

And I'm setting my state as follows:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    // getList promise is confirmed to be providing an array
    this._asyncRequest = getList().then(
      itemList => {
        this._asyncRequest = null;
        // breakpoint confirms itemList is array at this time
        this.setState({itemList});
      }
    );
  }
```

A breakpoint placed just before the `itemList.map` call shows that itemList is actually an object containing the actual itemList array that I'm looking for, like so:

```
itemList:
{
  itemList: [ ... ]
}
```

Instead of what I expect, which would be:

```
itemList:
[ ... ]
```

Why is my array being trasformed into a self-titled object that contains my array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In React, if you pass props to a functional component as `<ListingContainer itemList={this.state.itemList} />` it will be accessible inside an object called props or anything you named it.

Here `const ListingContainer = (itemList) => {...}` you have named that object as `itemList`. That's why you are getting the result `itemList.itemList = [ ... ]`.

So, you can change your code i.e. use destructuring  as `{itemList}`

```
const ListingContainer = ({itemList}) => {
    return(
        <div>
            {
                // getting type error, itemList.map is not a function
                itemList.map(({data}) => <Item data={data} />)
            }
        </div>
    );
};
```

or  without destructuring

```
const ListingContainer = (props) => {
        return(
            <div>
                {
                    props.itemList.map(({data}) => <Item data={data} />)
                }
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Comment: Does not answer the question.  What am I doing wrong to cause my Array to be transformed into an object that *needs* to be destructured in the first place?

Comment: `ListingContainer` component expects a parameter `props` which is an object and you can call it anything. In your case you have replaced `props` as `itemList`.This is how `React` works. If you pass `props` to a functional component as `<ListingContainer itemList={this.state.itemList} />` it will be accessible inside an object called `props` or anything you named it. That's why you are getting the result `itemList.itemList = [ ... ]`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  If you update the answer to clarify with this comment info, I'll mark it as the solution.